# Https: not working but :443/ work?

Tags: debian, ssl, https, tls

I don't understand (on debian) why I can access to my website using http://www.myserver.com:**443**/ but not directly with **https**://...

I'm using LetsEncrypt, all my cert' are generates and works.
Here my .../apache2/site-enabled/default.conf:

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ServerName myServer.com
    ServerAlias www.myServer.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.myServer.com/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/MyServer.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/MyServer.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/MyServer.com/fullchain.pem
```

Comment: If http://foo:443 works, then you've truly messed up something, as your server is serving http over the https port. Please include your entire config, not just a snippet of it.

Comment: Isn't there a certificate file missing there? I used LetsEncryt a while ago but I think you are missing one there. Also, as @EEAA said, post all the info please, connecting to whatever:443 doesn't mean that you are connecting to ssl over http.